# opencv setting submat of Mat to another Mat

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am having problems using the setTo() method. My code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Mat> someImagesOfSameSize = new ArrayList<Mat>;
someImagesOfSameSize.add(img1);
someImagesOfSameSize.add(img3);
someImagesOfSameSize.add(img3);
Mat combinedImagesOfSameSize = new Mat(new Range(0,30), new Range(0,100*someImagesOfSameSize.size()),3);
Mat tempImage = null;
for(int i = 0; someImagesOfSameSize.size();i++){
    tempImage = someImagesOfSameSize.get(i);
    combinedImagesOfSameSize.submat(new Range(0,30), new Range(i*100,(i+1)*100)).setTo(tempImage)
}
```

It gives me the following OpenCV Error:

***OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (checkScalar(value, type(), _value.kind(), _InputArray::MAT )) in 
unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp, line 348 Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp:348: error: (-215) checkScalar(value, type(), _value.kind(), _InputArray::MAT )] at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_setTo(Native Method) at org.opencv.core.Mat.setTo(Mat.java:2164)***

What i want to do is simple:
Take one image at a time, write it into the combined image, shift the columns to the right and so on. Since they have all the same size it should be possible.
Could someone point out why this doesn't work ?

Comment: I found my mistake. The combined Mat should be initialzied like this: "Mat combinedImagesOfSameSize = new Mat(new Range(0,30), new Range(0,100*someImagesOfSameSize.size()),CvType.CV_8UC3);" Thought putting a 3 there reads a 3 channel png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having studied the opencv Java API more thoroughly i found out that, the Contructor `Mat(Range rowRange, Range colRange, int type)` is misused by my code, because **"type"** here refers to CvType. This means that i have to supply the image type the Mat is going to resemble. I set this value to **"CvType.CV_8UC3"**, since my "someImagesOfSameSize"-images were 3-channel 8-bit png-files.

Another thing, that i have changed is, i am using the copyTo()-method to write into the submatrix of combined-image, so the code inside the for loop changes to:

```
tempSameSizeImage.copyTo(combinedSameSizeImages.submat(
                new Range(0, 61), new Range(i * 160, (i + 1) * 160)));
```